# SQL Server INSERT trigger to set initial dates syntax

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I've looked at some posts regarding updating on an `INSERT` trigger. My question is similar, but I wary of my syntax on the `UPDATE` statement, especially not understanding a table that keeps getting referred to as `INSERTED`.

The trigger code will update some date column values on `INSERT` only (and thanks to some code I've found here from one of you gurus, there is logic to handle the `'shipdueDate'` column).

There is already an incremented value for the Invoice number based on an Identifier setting, so when a new row is created, the invoice number is incremented by 1. However, in order to make it easier for an admin in the office to add invoice data, I thought placing some initial values in the `orderdate`, `shipduedate`, and `dateinvoiced` fields would allow easier data entry.

This is the code I've come up with

```
   CREATE TRIGGER Invoices_SetInitialDates ON dbo.Invoices FOR INSERT
   AS 
   BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @fromDate DATETIME
  DECLARE @shipDate DATETIME
  DECLARE @daysToAdd int
    -- We promise a 7 day turn-around on orders, so it has to 
    -- ship on the 8th day
  SELECT @fromDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @DaysToAdd = 8
  SET datefirst 1

    -- code from stackoverflow to calculate the shipduedate based
    -- on week days. It doesn't have any logic for holidays, but it
    -- provides the Admin initial values to work with, and that she 
    -- can change in the new record.
      SELECT @shipDate =
        DATEADD(day,
        @daysToAdd%5 +
         CASE DATEPART(weekday,@fromDate) + @daysToAdd%5
           WHEN 6 THEN 2
           WHEN 7 THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END,
         DATEADD(week,@daysToAdd/5,@fromDate)
       )

       -- UPDATE statement for trigger here. I'm not sure
       -- here about a table called INSERTED, or if this will
       -- simply update the newly added record. This is where
       -- I believe I need guidance.
         UPDATE dbo.Invoices SET DateOrdered = @fromDate
         ,ShipDueDate = @shipDate
         ,DateInvoiced = @fromDate

       END
       GO
```

Thanks in advance. This is a great site with a lot of SQL Server talent.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned only about `INSERT`, then there's absolutely no need for a trigger - just define defaults for your columns!

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Invoices
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Invoices_DateOrdered DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR DateOrdered

ALTER TABLE dbo.Invoices
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Invoices_DateInvoiced DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR DateInvoiced
```

The `ShipDueDate` with its calculation logic is a bit of a trickier business - but maybe you can simplify that so you can define it as a default constraint, too.

Default constraints provide values to your columns **upon `INSERT`**, but only if the `INSERT` statement doesn't explicitly set those columns to some other value.

Comment: @ marc_s - Thanks. This is a good alternative for fields that just need the current date. The shipduedate, like you say is a calculation and I'm hoping to keep all of these default values housed in a single location. Nevertheless it's appreciated. Hope this isn't breaking some rule, but wanted ask if you live in Nova Scotia? I ask, only because I was born there.

Comment: @CliffRobinson: nope, just a big fan of Bluenose country after I worked there for three years - I was born and raised (and now live) in Switzerland

Answer (score 0):

Let me fisrt explain about inserted (and deleted). In a trigger youhavea availabel two tables which contain the data you are going to insert or delete. In an update , the old values are in deleted and the new values are in inserted. In a delete only deleted is populated. In an insert only inserted is populated. NOw the key thing to remember is that you can never rely on a trigger to only have one record in this inserted or deleted. If you inserted 100 records in one insert statement, then there are 100 records in inserted. Therefore code will not work properly if you assume only one record.  A clue is that you shoudl not be setting a value from inserted to a scalar variable.

Your trigger needs to join to inserted in the update statment as right now it would update every record in the table with the new dates.

something like:

```
UPDATE inv
SET DateOrdered = @fromDate          
    ,ShipDueDate = @shipDate          
    ,DateInvoiced = @fromDate  
From dbo.Invoices inv
join inserted i on inv.id = i.id
```

Comment: Thank you. So in an effort to understand :) - this table 'inserted' comes from where? Is it a SQL SVR mechanism to hold a copy of the table your in essence performing a delete and insert against? Also, the PK for Invoices is InvoiceID. Should I assume that inv.id should be InvoiceID = i.id or should it be Invoices.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID?

Comment: Sorry, the above question is addressed to you @HLGEM. I tried adding the code with inv.invoiceid = i.invoiceid and that didn't seem to work. Should I try --> join inserted i on inv.invoiceid = i.id? Your clarification would be most welcome.

Comment: Inserted has the same columns names as the table that is being inserted into. Inserted is not a real table but is only available to you in a trigger or the output clause of a query.